# Show/hide div on select tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have tried several time to hide div in laravel framework but the code is not working. There is some error with my JS code, I can't find it. Although its working in js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/3823/

There are 2 fields in a form: User Type & Role. When a user selects User Type as "Owner" I want the Role field to get hide else Role field should be displayed.

```
<select id="basic" name="usertype" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" >

   @if(isset($user->usertype))  
        <option value="Owner" type="dropdown" @if($user->usertype=='Owner') selected  @endif >Owner</option>
        <option value="User" type="dropdown" @if($user->usertype=='User') selected @endif >User</option>
    @else
        <option value="Owner" type="dropdown">Owner</option>
        <option value="User" type="dropdown">User</option>                                 
    @endif 



</select>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#basic').click(function(){
            if($(this).attr('value')=="Owner"){
            $('div#user_role').hide();
        }
        else{
            $('div#user_role').show();
        }
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="form-group" id="user_role">
    <label for="" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Role</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select name="role" id="" class="form-control">
             <option value="student" >Student</option>
             <option value="faculty">Faculty</option>
             <option value="management">Management</option>
         </select> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to use `change` instead of `click`. `$(this).val()` is the same as `$(this).attr('value')` and `$('div#user_role')` is overkill, `$('#user_role')` should already be enough as the ID should be unique.

Comment: still not working. yeah i did that change. @putvande

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are hiding the select on click, try with change event.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function(){
    $("#basic").change(function(){
      
      var value     = $(this).val();
      var user_role = $("#user_role"); 
      
      if(value == "Owner"){
        user_role.hide();
      }else{
        user_role.show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#user_role{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="basic" name="usertype">
  <option value="Owner" >Owner</option>
  <option value="User">User</option>
</select>

<select id="user_role">
  <option value="student">Student</option>
  <option value="faculty">Faculty</option>
  <option value="management">Management</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, you just need to add `$('#user_role').hide();` on `onload` as your script is getting called on `onclick` event so it gets called after click and your default option is owner.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/3825/

Comment: It is hiding Role field but then it's not opening even selecting User Type as "User"

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/3825/) is working fine for me. Can you replicate your issue on fiddle?

Comment: Earlier it worked fine for me too but on live project its not working.

Comment: I placed the same code in my file but it's not working.